# How can I get items in my bibliography listed with square brackets?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, brackets

I would like to use square brackets for citations in the text and in the bibliography.
I figured out how to adapt the citations in the text, but I just don't find any way how to change the appearance of my bibliography.

I am "condemned" to use a pre-defined document class. With this, I didn't need to insert a bibliographystyle. Instead, the bibliography could simply be created by inserting the command \bibliography{bib-file} in the text. There was also the option to change the style of citation in the text by using \citestyle{plain}. However, I don't know where both of those commands are configured or where they can be adapted. So the question is: Which are the corresponding files or parts to change the style of the bibliography?

Thanks

Comment: For a detailed (thus good) answers you will have to prepare a *self-contained* and [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) because speculations about the probable cause due to missing information won't help you.

Comment: It would be of very interesting to know what `\bibliographystyle` you are using and what you have done to get square brackets in text citations and where you want square brackets in the bibliography.

Comment: Hi Thorsten and Moewe. Sorry, I should have mentioned that I am using a pre-defined document class so I didn't need to insert a bibliographystyle. Instead, the bibliography could simply be created by inserting the command \bibliography{bib-file} . There was also the option to change the style of citation in the text by using \citestyle{plain}. 
However, I don't know where both of those commands are configured or where they can be adapted. So the proper question would probably be: Which are the corresponding files to change the style of the bibliography

Comment: Obviously your class is setting up the bibliography style and so - as you didn't tell us anything about this class - you are the only one who can know how to change it.

Comment: We indeed would need to see the custom class. Standard `\bibliographystyle{plain}` (with `natbib`) puts the citations into square brackets by default, so this might be an option for you. However, if you *have* to use a certain documentclass, are you then allowed to change the bibliography/citation styles?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You might have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) if you wish to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't publish the document class here, but thank you for your help!

Comment: See if you can find a `\bibliographystyle` in the class file then, if you cannot post it here. moewe also has a point though, if you have to use this style, should you really change it?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using natbib? It's hard without an MWE ... Anyway,

```
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
```

does exactly that for me, i.e. square bracktes.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, as I have no information for anything better.

If you have the option to use `\citestyle{plain}` in your text to change the style of the citation, I'd imagine this macro wraps `\bibliographystyle` and that its argument is the `bst` file to be used.  Pick a style that generates the citations the way you want them, e.g. `ieeetr.bst` (if that's good for you), and try adding `\citestyle{ieeetr}`.

If this does not work, this probably means that the set of options you have with `\citestyle` is predefined and that, maybe, the people who provided you with this class do not want you to change the way citations look and tried to ensure you couldn't.